# UnboundLocalError local variable 'context' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I am stuck at this error(UnboundLocalError local variable 'context' referenced before assignment) while saving form of almost same type other are working fine but this one is not and showing error

```
def clutchDetail(request):

clutchDetail = ClutchDetail.objects.all()
context = {'title': 'Clutch Detail',
           'active': 'active',
           'clutchDetail': clutchDetail,
           }
return render(request, 'breedingRecApp/clutch_detail.html', context)
```

def clutchDetail_add(request):

```
if request.method == "POST":
    form = ClutchDetail_AddModelForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        try:
            form.save()
            return redirect('breedingRecApp:clutch_detail')

        except:
            pass
else:
    form = ClutchDetail_AddModelForm()
    context = {'title': 'Species Detail Add',
               'active': 'active',
               'model': ClutchDetail,
               'form': form,
               }
return render(request, 'breedingRecApp/clutch_detail_add.html', context)
```

Please help me to fix this error I am newbie to Django. I've an other form code which 100% same that is working fine but this one gives me an error I am stuck at it:(

Comment: In case the method is a POST, but the `form.is_valid()` fails, or `form.save()` raises an exception, you never set the `context` variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Talking about the second code block*

The only place

```
context
```

is defined is on line 12

```
context = {'title': 'Species Detail Add',
```

this only runs when the else: statement is triggered, so when

```
return render(request, 'breedingRecApp/clutch_detail_add.html', context)
```

context would not be defined if the else statement was not triggered
Cheers!

Comment: Thanks! I re-place the context variable now error has gone but my data is not saving in DB. I've same code for other form that is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you get this error is because your function contains a codepath where you *use* the `context` variable, without *defining* the variable first. That is for example the case when you make a POST request, but the `form.is_valid()` check fails. In that case, the codeflow will call the `render(..)` function, but you did not define the `context` variable.

The smallest fix would probably be to move the definition of the `context` variable *outside* the `else` statement:

```
def clutchDetail_add(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ClutchDetail_AddModelForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('breedingRecApp:clutch_detail')
    else:
        form = ClutchDetail_AddModelForm()
    context = {
        'title': 'Species Detail Add',
        'active': 'active',
        'model': ClutchDetail,
        'form': form,
    }
    return render(request, 'breedingRecApp/clutch_detail_add.html', context)
```

Comment: @s4starb4boy: of course it is not, since the form is not valid. Since the `form.is_valid()` returns `False`, that means that you entered a value that is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

In the case that the method is a POST and the `form.is_valid()` returns `False`, or `form.save()` raises an exception this error is raised as you never declared the context variable.

You also probably don't need to do `try: except:` on your `form.save()` call as the form is valid at that point.

```
def clutchDetail(request):

    clutchDetail = ClutchDetail.objects.all()
    context = {'title': 'Clutch Detail',
           'active': 'active',
           'clutchDetail': clutchDetail,
           }
    return render(request, 'breedingRecApp/clutch_detail.html', context)

def clutchDetail_add(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ClutchDetail_AddModelForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('breedingRecApp:clutch_detail')
    else:
        form = ClutchDetail_AddModelForm()

    context = {'title': 'Species Detail Add',
               'active': 'active',
               'model': ClutchDetail,
               'form': form,
    }
    return render(request, 'breedingRecApp/clutch_detail_add.html', context)
```

Comment: That's unfortunately because your form is invalid. There's a line that does if form.is_valid(), only if that returns True will it proceed to form.save() ; what does it say if you do print(form.errors) ?